# WLAN router for 802.1X (RADIUS) testing

Tags: router, switch, wlan

We're developing devices that shall support 802.1X authentication. For testing purposes, we need to connect a few of them to a switch / router.

We need

- "usual" WLAN (802.11b/g/n)
- 7 100 MBit Ethernet ports + 1 Uplink port
- Management of at least 12 devices possible
- support for username + passwort authentication
- support for certificate authentication
- cost max. 1500 €

So far, I found a [Lancom WLC-4006+](https://www.lancom-systems.de/en/products/wireless-lan/controller/lancom-wlc-4006plus/lancom-wlc-4006plus-overview/), but it has 4+1 Ethernet ports only.

Answer (score 1):

One cheap option would be the **D-Link DIR-632**. It supports all of the above requirements, save perhaps "management of at least 12 devices possible," using [dd-wrt firmware](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/D-Link_DIR-632), possibly also stock firmware. I can't think of a reason why it wouldn't support 12 managed devices simultaneously, so I think it is a good suggestion.

It is worth noting that this is in a totally different class of devices from your Lancom WLC-4006+, which is not a router or a switch but a *WLAN Controller,* which is designed to manage connections to wireless APs.

Resource on configuring it to [work with certificates under dd-wrt](http://andrewbevitt.com/tutorials/dd-wrt-radius-authentication-w-server-2008-r2/).